# ASP.NET MVC Binding to a Dictionary in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that binds data to a Model. **Simple** objects within the Model are working perfectly like: **ContactName** and **Telephone**.

I am doing this by simply having: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactName)`

The Model contains a Dictionary object which isn't getting binded with my current implementation.

Can anyone give me an example of how I can do this? The current code I have for binding to a Dictionary is:

```
<div>
@*TABS*@
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Translations.Count; i++)
{
<li class="@i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"><a href="#@Model.Translations.Keys.ToList()[i]" data-toggle="tab">@Model.Translations.Keys.ToList()[i]</a></li>
}
</ul>

@*TABCONTENT*@
   <div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;">

     @foreach (var translation in Model.Translations)
     {
       for (var i = 0; i < Model.Translations.Count; i++)
        {
         <div class="@i == 0 ? 'active' : ''" id="@translation.Value.CultureCode">@translation.Value.Title</div>
        }
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => translation.Value.Title[]);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => translation.Value.FullDescription);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => translation.Value.PreviewDescription);
}
</div>
</div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using @Html.EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor? As the name says, TextBox will always try to render a textbox to bind to the data supplied, while EditorFor will try to find an appropriate template that matches best. It might not have a template for that, and if it doesnt, I would still suggest the swtich to EditorFor, followed by writing yourself a template. It would keep your views cleaner. Let me know if you need me to write a more detailed answer on how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "your list property"[index].value.id
example
if you have:

```
public IList<KeyValuePair<int,string>> Properties { get; set; }
```

you should write in view:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(item=>Model.Properties[i].Value)
}
```

**updated:**

```
 @for (var i=0; i < Model.Translations.Count; i++) { 
        <div id="tabs-@(i)">
            <div class="@i == 0 ? 'active' : ''" id="@Model.Translations[i].Value.CultureCode">@Model.Translations[i].Value.Title</div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Translations[i].Value.Title);
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Translations[i].Value.FullDescription);
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Translations[i].Value.PreviewDescription);  }
        </div>

    </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am considering translation is the Dictionary Object:

```
  @foreach (var category in translation) {

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => category.Value.Title);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => category.Value.FullDescription);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => category.Value.PreviewDescription);

    }
```